# How to resize Excel Range copied as a Picture to Word?

Tags: vba, image, copy, image-resizing

I copy a part of a range from a Excel table to Word as a picture.

Next I want to resize the picture in a way that it is always the same size.   It worked one time, but now it does not.

```vb
Sub InsertPictureOfTable()
'    Dim W As Word.Application
'    Dim d As Word.Document
'    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim objInlineShape As InlineShape
    
    With WordApp.Selection
        ' Copy table to buffer
        Tabelle1.Range("Punktetabelle").Copy

        ' Paste table from clipboard
        doc.Bookmarks("Punktetabelle2").Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine

        ' Get reference to the InlineShape object of the inserted image
        Set objInlineShape = doc.InlineShapes(doc.InlineShapes.Count)

        ' Change the size of the image
        With objInlineShape
            .Width = 574
            .Height = 667
        End With
        
        ' Centre image
        With objInlineShape.Range.Paragraphs(1)
            .Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter ' Center the paragraph horizontally
            .SpaceBefore = 0 ' Remove any space before the paragraph
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried different sizes and restarted the computer and Excel several times.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile in Excel. You are referring to `W as Word.Application` and `WordApp`. Your comments are in German, your post must be in English on `StackOverflow.com`. Please edit your post and correct those errors and check that it compiles with `Option Explicit` in force.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I translated the comments and "outcommented" every variable that isn't used. The shown code is just part of a subroutine, there is a "Option Explicit" at the beginning. The code is working so far, it copies the range as a picture into the bookmark, but its not resized.

Comment: So `WordApp` is a global Var that is set outside the Sub?

Comment: Yes, in the beginning of the Module: 
~~~Option Explicit
Dim ZeileAllgemein As Long
Dim countTask As Integer
Public doc As Word.Document
Dim WordApp As New Word.Application
Dim OutlookApplication As Object ~~~

Comment: There is no Error while using the code, only the size of the picture is not changed, maybe that information helps to find my mistake.

Comment: Are you sure that `doc.InlineShapes(doc.InlineShapes.Count)` is the one you want?  If in Word I run `doc.InlineShapes(doc.InlineShapes.Count).Select` it selects the last shape in the document (the one closest to the end of the document), not the last-pasted shape.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an inline shape by pasting, it won't be returned by

`doc.InlineShapes(doc.InlineShapes.Count)`

unless it's the last one in the document (ie. you won't get the *last-inserted* shape, but the last in document order)

You could try something like this instead (I tested this in Word):

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim doc As Document, rng As Range, pos As Long, shp As InlineShape
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    Set rng = doc.Bookmarks("Punktetabelle2").Range
    pos = rng.Start              'start of the paste destination range
    rng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, Placement:=wdInLine
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = doc.Range(pos, doc.Content.End).InlineShapes(1) 'try to find the pasted shape
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        shp.Select 'or resize etc
    Else
        MsgBox "Pasted shape not found!"
    End If

End Sub
```